# Ionic grid alignment row and column with column offset

Tags: ionic-framework

I have the following content in ionic.

```
  <ion-content>
  <div class="row row-center">
    <div class="col-150 col-offset-50"><h4>Login</h4></div> </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-10 col-offset-50"><h4>Username</h4></div>
    <div class=" col-10 col-offset-5"><label class="item item-input">   
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username">  
    </label></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="row row-bottom">
    <div class=" col-10 col-offset-50"><h4>Password</h4></div>
    <div class=" col-10 col-offset-5"><label class="item item-input">  
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">  
    </label>
    </div> 
    </div>
    </ion-content>
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

I am new to ionic and would really appreciate some help in

1)space between the two rows for username and password

2)Aligning both the username and password rows a little more to the left so that the Login row looks centered.

Comment: Hey there,
1.) you missed the "col" class before your col-x class. It won't work without it. For e.g.  <div class="col col-150 col-offset-50"> see [link]http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-offset
2.) I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve... do you want to center the "login" row? Or centering all? (offset-50 means 50%?). I think this code needs some optimization but we need to know what it should look like at the end =)

Comment: Not sure what it's supposed to look like, you "output looks like this" doesn't seem to reference anything.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use inline labels?

To align all labels to center, add text-center class to your labels.

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label text-center">Login</span>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label text-center">Username</span>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label text-center">Password</span>
      <input type="password">
    </label>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

To centrally align just 'Login' label, add text-center just to that label

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="list">
    <label class="item text-center">
      Login
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Username</span>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Password</span>
      <input type="password">
    </label>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

To add space between items, add margin-bottom to .input-label class. Don't do this in the original ionic css file - create another stylesheet to contain all your overrides.